# Pip downloading for old python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a problem downloading pip for python 2.7 in 2022
How can I download it?

I tried

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But it gave

```
No module named pip
```

Comment: `python -m ensurepip` might help ..

Comment: it gave no modual named ensurepip

Answer (score 0):

Download the file https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py . Then run (in the directory where `get-pip.py` was downloaded)

```
python get-pip.py
python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `pip2` instead of `pip`